# Java regex - replace substrings between delimiters with same substrings without delimiters

Tags: java, regex, substring

I'm trying to figure out how to replace with Java 1.6 in strings like

```
hello ${world }!   ${txt + '_t'}<br/> ${do_not_replace
```

any substring identified between '${' and '}' with the same substring without these delimiters.
So the output for the string above should be

```
hello world !   txt + '_t'<br/> ${do_not_replace
```

I identified a working pattern that allows me to replace the substrings with a fixed string

```
str.replaceAll('[${](.*?)}', '_')
```

and i know that i cannot use named groups with this version of Java.

Any suggestion for a simple solution to this problem are highly appreciated! Many thanks

Comment: "and i know that i cannot use named groups with this version of Java" Numbered groups are OK, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
    s = s.replaceAll("\\$\\{(.+?)}", "$1");
```

Comment: [Dasblinkenlight](http://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight)'s solution is perfectly valid as well, so thank you both!