# Regex Replace $nth element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible that I replace the `$n` element with a particular string?
In my example the `$1` element.

For example, i want to replace the last element of a url 
`"http://my.domain.com/sub/file.extension"` with my string `"other.other"`.

my regex is something like this : `/([^/]+)\.extension$`

But it also replaces the slash before "file".

Here is a complete example:

```
var url = "http://my.domain.com/sub/file.extension";
var replace = "other.other";
var regex = new RegExp("/([^/]+)$");
console.log(url.replace(regex,replace));
```

I know i could prepend the slash in my replace like this: `var replace = "/other.other";` but I want a different approach, that I could also use in other Projects.

In short, I am looking for a possibility to replace something without the delimiting character to replace with.

**PS:**
I read something about positive lookahead, but I can't get it to work.
And I know about [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183/replacing-the-nth-instance-of-a-regex-match-in-javascript) and [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057664/java-regex-replace-substrings-between-delimiters-with-same-substrings-without), but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just for explanation: I deleted my answer as other answers have been added while I fixed mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change has been made within your code .try the below code and check

```
var url = "http://my.domain.com/sub/file.extension";
var replace = "other.other";
var regex = new RegExp("([^/]+)$");
console.log(url.replace(regex,replace));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://my.domain.com/sub/file.extension";
url = url.split("/");
url.pop();
url.push("other.other");
url = url.join("/");
console.log(url);
```

[image]

Comment: `url.substring(0, url.lastIndexof('/')+1) + replace` is a bit more compact and does the same. OP stated that he needs a regular expression for some reasons, though.